OpenXML Error when creating new WorksheetPart
So first off, my code works in a console application. I installed OpenXML via NuGet into the solution.
I created a new solution that is a .NET dll library and installed openXML the same way and deployed the dll with the OpenXML dlls and when my dll is called, I'm getting an error as shown below.
OpenXML that is installed is 3.0.2
VerificationException: Method DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.OpenXmlPartContainer.AddNewPart: type argument 'DocumentFormat.OpenXml.Packaging.WorksheetPart' violates the constraint of type parameter 'T'.
I've commented out most of my code to try to isolate where this is happening and I think I've found it. Interesting, when it does throw the error, it doesn't even step into the routine CreateExcel(). But when I comment out a certain line of code, it will step through. Here is the basic structure I have.
My main routine.
internal static void CreateRawMtlExcel(List<RawMtl> Mtls, string OutputPath)
        {
            //SpreadsheetDocument spreadsheetDocument = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(string.Format(@"{0}\{1}MexRawMtls.xlsx", OutputPath), SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook);

            using (SpreadsheetDocument package = SpreadsheetDocument.Create(OutputPath, SpreadsheetDocumentType.Workbook))
            {
                CreateExcel(package, Mtls);
            }
        }


private static void CreateExcel(SpreadsheetDocument document, List<RawMtl> Mtls)
        {

            WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.AddWorkbookPart();
            workbookPart.Workbook = new Workbook();
            WorksheetPart worksheetPart = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorksheetPart>(); //This seems to be the line that is causing issues. 
            
            SheetData sheetData = new SheetData();

            worksheetPart.Worksheet = new Worksheet(sheetData);
            //Columns hColumns = GetHeaderColumns();

            //Sheets sheets = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.
            //    AppendChild<Sheets>(new Sheets());

            //// Append a new worksheet and associate it with the workbook.
            //Sheet sheet = new Sheet()
            //{
            //    Id = document.WorkbookPart.
            //    GetIdOfPart(worksheetPart),
            //    SheetId = 1,
            //    Name = "Raw Materials"
            //};

            //sheets.Append(sheet);
            //var sheetdata = worksheetPart.Worksheet.GetFirstChild<SheetData>();

            ////worksheetPart.Worksheet.InsertBefore(hColumns, sheetdata);
            ////WorkbookStylesPart workbookStylesPart1 = workbookPart.AddNewPart<WorkbookStylesPart>("rId3");
            ////GenerateWorkbookStylesContent(workbookStylesPart1);

            workbookPart.Workbook.Save();
        }


I found the answer. So first I tested this by creating a separate console app and referencing the dll and it worked. So the issue was how it was being called. I'm calling my dll within a 3rd party program which has an OpenXML reference already and it was an older version. 2.12.1   When I downgraded mine, everything worked.

I found the answer. So first I tested this by creating a separate console app and referencing the dll and it worked. So the issue was how it was being called. I'm calling my dll within a 3rd party program which has an OpenXML reference already and it was an older version. 2.12.1 When I downgraded mine, everything worked.
